# Generate a data frame from a set of strings

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a set of strings as follows in a file :

- SAMSUNG LCD TV40 B450
- SMALL 14 INCH WEGASONIC TVS
- SOINY LCD TV22 T400A
- SONY BRAVIA TV32 T550
- SONY BRAVIA TV40 S530
- SONY BRAVIA TV40 S530
- SONY BRAVIA TV42 S530A
- SONY BRVIA TV32 S550A
- SONY LCD TV19 T400A
- SONY LCD TV22 BX300
- SONY LCD TV22 T400A
- SONY LCD TV22 T400A
- SONY LCD TV22 T550
- SONY LCD TV26 BX300
- SONY LCD TV32 BX300
- SONY LCD TVV19 BX300
- STAR TV 21 MODEL 2103P
- TELESTAR 14 1486 COLOUR TV
- TELESTAR TV 14 1486
- TELESTAR TV 14 1486

I need to convert these strings into a data frame, where each unique word in the above list becomes column name. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Are all these strings a single vector or how are they currently organised? And do you only want an empty data.frame with only column names or should each column have some entries as well?

Comment: could you please post the expected output for a test case

Comment: In the above output will be a data frame with columns : Samsung, Sony, Bravia, Telestar, LCD, TV etc... Cell value for cell(i,j) = 1 if, string i has column name j (eg. Samsung) in it,otherwise 0

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your Strings are organised in a vector, and that you actually want a column for each unique word, you could do something like this.

```
strVec <- c("SONY BRAVIA TV32 T550","SONY BRAVIA TV40 S530","SONY BRAVIA TV40 S530","SONY BRAVIA TV42 S530A") 
words <- sapply(strVec,FUN=function(x) strsplit(x," ")) #split strings at " "
uniqueWords <- unique(unlist(words)) # get the unique words
mydf <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=0,ncol=length(uniqueWords))) # create new df
colnames(mydf) <- uniqueWords # give it the right colnames
```

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you wanted.  Also, you have `SOINY` along with `SONY`, spaces between `TV` and `number`.  Hope it is not the case in your actual dataset.

```
Lines <- readLines(n=20)
SAMSUNG LCD TV40 B450
SMALL 14 INCH WEGASONIC TVS
SONY LCD TV22 T400A
SONY BRAVIA TV32 T550
SONY BRAVIA TV40 S530
SONY BRAVIA TV40 S530
SONY BRAVIA TV42 S530A
SONY BRVIA TV32 S550A
SONY LCD TV19 T400A
SONY LCD TV22 BX300
SONY LCD TV22 T400A
SONY LCD TV22 T400A
SONY LCD TV22 T550
SONY LCD TV26 BX300
SONY LCD TV32 BX300
SONY LCD TVV19 BX300
STAR TV 21 MODEL 2103P
TELESTAR 14 1486 COLOUR TV
TELESTAR TV 14 1486
TELESTAR TV 14 1486

library(stringr) 
Lines <- str_trim(Lines) #removes trailing and leading spaces
Un <- unique(scan(text=Lines, what="")) #extractunique words

res <- sapply(Un, function(.pat) grepl(.pat, Lines)) +0

 res[1:3,1:3]
 #      SAMSUNG LCD TV40
 #[1,]       1   1    1
 #[2,]       0   0    0
 #[3,]       0   1    0

 as.data.frame(res) #converts to dataframe.
```